# Hydrostatic force on movable hemispherical piston

Tags: forces, fluid-statics

I have been previously advised that any horizontal hydrostatic forces on the curved face of the piston will cancel out but I thought it would have an effect on the movement of the piston.

Am I wrong?
Based on the drawing attached:

- Q1. What is the vertical hydrostatic force acting on the piston?
- Q2. What is the horizontal hydrostatic force acting on the piston?
- Q3. If the water below the piston is sealed and can't escape, what would be the water pressure within this area?

[image: Tank and hemispherical piston]

Answer (score 0):

I am going to assume that the piston rod exerts no net force on the hemisphere, that there is no friction between the hemisphere and the cylinder, and that seals on the hemisphere and the rod prevent water from leaving the cylinder.  To get the force from the water pressure on the upper surface of the hemisphere one could integrate the (variable) vertical component of force on each segment of the upper surface, or we can replace the hemisphere with water.  (You may want to think of it as being enclosed in a thin film.)  Then the upward force,U, from water pressure on the bottom must equal the weight of the water plus the downward force, D, from the pressure on the top of the hemisphere. Solving for D:
D = ρgh(πR^2) – ρ((2/3)πR^3)g   =  7.4403E4 Nt
This downward force from water pressure will be the same no matter what material is in the hemisphere. (The horizontal components do cancel out.)
If we go back to the hemisphere of specific gravity 1.5, the pressure on the bottom (at the top of the cylinder) will need to greater in order to support the extra weight. Hence the need for the seals. In this case solving for U gives:
U = (1.5ρg)(2/3)πR^3 + D = 7.8252E4 Nt and P = 9.9633E4 Nt/m^2 as compared with 9.8E4 Nt/m^2 at the bottom of the tank.

Comment: Thank you for your response- it is greatly appreciated.
I thought that the horizontal hydrostatic forces acting on the hemisphere would push it downwards as this is what would happen if it were solid forces acting on the same curved surface?
I understand that the vertical hydrostatic force will be determined by the mass of the water above the hemisphere, but I thought that the other forces would be perpendicular to the surface of the hemisphere. I see the surface of the hemisphere as thousands of tiny squares and these squares are perpendicular to the surface and not horizontal.

Comment: The thousands of tiny squares would be used to get the downward force by integration.

Comment: Note that I have corrected the formula for U by adding a g.

Comment: Thanks again for your reply.Does the hemisphere piston transfer more downwards force to the water below as it has a greater surface area, or would a flat head piston of the same radius transfer the same force to the water below?

Comment: The hemisphere is flat on the bottom.  If it were flat on both top and bottom but with the same volume, it would require the same extra force from the bottom because of its extra density.

Comment: I am trying to get a piston shape to maximise the pressure on the water on the flat surface below it. Would a concave or wedge shaped piston alter the pressure on the water below the piston in the cylinder?

Comment: To increase the force at the bottom, use a heavier piston or a deeper tank. The shape makes no difference for a given volume of piston. (Again, consider replacing it by water.)

Comment: Thanks again for the response- I think you have helped me to resolve the issue.